# ONSUCCESS event doesn't fire on dynamically created recordForm component

Tags: dynamic, lightning-record-form

I'm trying to get the saved data from my recordForm component handling the onsuccess event but the controller's function handling the event is not triggered. I think this happens because my component is dynamically crated.

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Thank you!

componentConroller.js

```
 handleNewRecordAdder : function(component, event, handler) {

    var sObjectType = event.getParam("data");
    var fields = ["Name"];
    component.set("v.isActive", true);
    component.set("v.loading", true);

    $A.createComponent(
        "lightning:recordForm",
        {
            "aura:id": "sobjectAdder",
            "objectApiName" : sObjectType,
            "fields" : fields,
            "columns" : "1",
            "mode" : "Edit",
            "onsuccess" : "{!c.handleSuccess}"
        },
        function(recordForm, status, errorMessage){
            //Add the new button to the body array
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {

                var container = component.find("container");
                component.set("v.loading", false);
                container.set("v.body", recordForm);
            }
            else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                // Show offline error
            }
            else if (status === "ERROR") {
                console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                // Show error message
            }
        }
    );

},
handleSuccess : function(component, event, helper) {

    console.log("done");
} 

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **getReference** method of Component to tell the button that which methods needs to call.

```
component.getReference("c.handleSuccess")
```

Your code will look like below

```
 handleNewRecordAdder : function(component, event, handler) {

    var sObjectType = event.getParam("data");
    var fields = ["Name"];
    component.set("v.isActive", true);
    component.set("v.loading", true);

    $A.createComponent(
        "lightning:recordForm",
        {
            "aura:id": "sobjectAdder",
            "objectApiName" : sObjectType,
            "fields" : fields,
            "columns" : "1",
            "mode" : "Edit",
            "onsuccess" : component.getReference("c.handleSuccess")
        },
        function(recordForm, status, errorMessage){
            //Add the new button to the body array
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {

                var container = component.find("container");
                component.set("v.loading", false);
                container.set("v.body", recordForm);
            }
            else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                // Show offline error
            }
            else if (status === "ERROR") {
                console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                // Show error message
            }
        }
    );

},
handleSuccess : function(component, event, helper) {

    console.log("done");
} 

})
```

Refer the given link: - 
[Dynamically Creating Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm)